# Ethernet audio transmitter for long ranges?

Tags: audio, ethernet, transmission

I need to make up a solution for transferring audio file from server to speakers (preferred option via Ethernet). The problem is that in worst case the server may be ~300 km away. Is there any Ethernet transmitter for such a long ranges or can u help me in making up some new solution without sending the file to another computer and then transferring to speakers? Thank you in advance for your ideas and help.

Comment: The fact you've got such a huge distance between source and destination will simply not work... an ultimate solution might be to get a device like a Raspberry Pi and use this as the media player... Either way - because you have speakers - you would therefore have an amplifier which would require power so you would be able to power the media player from the amplifier power source...

Comment: In my opinion it will be the same if i use Raspberry Pi or computer at the destination... don´t u think? How are they solving this problem in example on railway stations?

Comment: We need more information on your requirements. Would streaming compressed MP3 audio, or even uncompressed FLAC, over the internet be an option? Presumably you don't intend to lay a 300km ethernet cable so it sounds like what you are asking is if you can make an existing ethernet based system work over the internet.

Comment: Uncompressed over internet will still be an option yes.

Comment: I think what's being forgotten here is that at the end of the cable you will need to decode the audio data and it will need to be converted to analogue... You haven't written about what the terminating mechanism is... how are you going to convert data to analogue?

Comment: Well actually I will use transmitter whose max transmit distance is 120 km and I will not consider the worst case (~300 km). On the other side I am planning to use audio receiver and I think that will do the work. Now I just need to see if the receivers have built in amplifiers and I use the output direct to the speaker or I will have to use an amplifier too.

Comment: Do you really have the option of running a 300 km ethernet cable from your server to your speakers ? Or when you say ethernet you mean internet ?

Comment: I was thinking about ethernet yes and 300 km is not an option anymore. But for ~100 km yes we're going to figure it out. It is an existing connection for a big enterprise owned by the state. I was trying to figure it out what kind of solutions can I use to transport on distances such as that. Internet is still an option too. Thanks for the help when I have the solution I will write it.